# How to embed audio files to markers on a Mapbox map?

Tags: mapbox, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to create an interactive map using Python and Flask, and hoping to embed one audio file to every marker on a Mapbox map, so that every time the user clicks on a marker, he or she hears an audio clip playing some sounds. How would this be achieved? I'm using this as a foundation for my map: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-a-marker/

I considered adding a popup for each marker on the map, but still not sure how to include the audio file in my popup?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should go with client side script instead of backend code.You can use the below script:

```
marker = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [longitude, latitude]
  },
  "properties": {
    "title": "Marker Title",
    "description": "Marker Description",
    "audio_url": "/path/to/your/audio/file.mp3"
    # Add the URL of your audio file here
  }
}


marker.on('click', function()
{
    var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
    offset: 25
        })
        .setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p>' +
            '<audio controls><source src="' + marker.properties.audio_url + '" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>'); // Add the HTML audio element to the popup
    popup.addTo(map);
});
```